# WPF ListItems isn't displayed properly if it's Content contains _

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have ListBox :

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="betOdds" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Where OddsList is `ObservableCollection<CheckBoxListItem>`

I init this collection with different objects, that have Name like "TEST", "TEST_1", "TEST_2", "OVERFLOW" etc. (Some names contains `_` symbol).

When I bind this collection to `ItemsSource` of `ListBox` and start App, I see that `ListItems` that don't have `_` in name are displayed.

Why is it?

When I select some items with empty content, it is still same elements with `_` symbol.

[image]

Comment: workaround would be replacing single underscore with double underscore so it would be treated as single underscore in content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the `Content` property to a `TextBlock`:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="betOdds" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <CheckBox.Content>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                    </CheckBox.Content>
                </CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

A character preceded by an underscore may be converted to an access key: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-accesstext/. But you could set the `Content` to a `TextBlock` to work around this.

Comment: yeah, this helps! Thanks. But Do you know why by default `_` isn't displayed?